# Maya Python - Playblast - save in a specific folder

Tags: maya

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import os


filepath = cmds.file(q=True, sn=True)
filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
raw_name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)

name = raw_name.replace(raw_name[-1::], ' ')

def test():
   test_play = cmds.playblast 
(s="ohNo",C:\Users\Julio\Desktop\test\row\name)

test()
```

I want to save a playblast with the name of the file and in a
specific folder but I can not combinate a fuction (name)
with a path. Any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from maya import cmds

movie_path = cmds.playblast(filename="c:/Users/Julio/Desktop/test/row/name")
print(movie_path)
```

Will produce a movie and print out its path:

```
c:\Users\Julio\Desktop\test\row\name.avi
```

Comment: You are welcome, @David. Consider marking this as solved so others could benefit from this answer as well.